# Why use iPhoto instead of manually saving images?

Tags: icloud, photos.app, image-capture

I would like to know whether there are any advantages to using iPhoto on Mac for my pictures taken on my iPhone. For the past few years I have simply exported all images via Image Capture which stores the actual file to a location on my hard drive. Recently I have had to use iPhoto to get images off an iCloud shared stream, I have noticed when importing the images it saves into one file (almost like a database) instead of individual JPEG files.

Can someone tell me whether what pros and cons are there to using iPhoto instead of manually saving images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most things you can do in iPhoto you can do in Preview and Finder, except a lot slower. Organization in iPhoto is more powerful than simply using a file system.

- You can sort:

  - by Event
  - by Location
  - by Person via facial recognition
- Arrange into albums (Unlike folders, photos can reside within multiple albums.)
- Shows extra metadata, such as:

  - Stars
  - Camera and settings used
  - Map position
- Allows basic image touch ups:

  - Color-grading
  - Auto touchup (really hand, fast and convenient)
  - Built in "straighten" function (also very useful)
  - Auto-enhance
  - Automatically retains "originals" in case you want to revert an edit
- Manages Facebook and Flickr albums